# Calculate the surface area with integration

Tags: integration, surfaces, surface-integrals

Calculate the surface area of the surface obtained when the region enclosed by the given curves is revolved about the $x$-axis
$$y=2x^2-8$$ $$y=x^2-1$$

This is a model problem for an exam and I really don't know what to do. I don't have any idea what shape will I get when the given curves are revolved around the x-axis. Can somebody help me with this problem?

[image]

[image]

Can I consider these areas for the calculation

Comment: You should first draw the curves and find where they interesect. [The shape you get before you revolve arund the x-axis will be*] a sort of inverted vee-shaped thing with curved edges, I expect. But you should draw it for yourself. Edit: [*]

Comment: @J.Dane Nice problem!

Comment: An upside-down symmetrical version of the star trek logo!

Comment: I drew it but I don't know how should I seperate the integral in order to calculate the surface because I don't think that the shape I get when I revolve the curves can be calculated with one integral

Comment: Do you want the volume of the shape obtained or the surface area of the shape obtained? @J.Dane

Comment: I want the surface area of the surface obtained.  Am I saying it right because English isn't my native language?

Comment: It's symmetrical about the y axis so I would calculate it as two times the three integrals in the 1st quadrant. Because the curves overlap each other, to get a better visual, add $y = -2x^2 + 8$ and $y = -x^2 + 1$ to your graph.

Comment: @J.Dane You are fine! I just wanted to make sure

Comment: I think you should split up the question into three parts as well. I would try these three intervals:  $$\left[-\sqrt{7},-2\right] \,\,\,\,\left[-2,-1\right]\,\,\,\,\left[-1,0\right]$$

Comment: The question is totally unclear, and so the so-called model exam is extremely poorly set. What on earth is "the surface obtained when the region enclosed by the given curves is revolved about the $x$-axis"?? It intersects itself, so do we ignore the part of the surface that is embedded? It also has a hole in the middle, so do we ignore the hole? Holes also have surface area...

Comment: @user21820 That's what I'm trying to figure it out too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't do the whole problem but the $3$ surfaces are on the intervals $[0, 1.7320508],$

$[1.7320508, 2.6457513]\ \text{and} \ [2, 2.6457513]$ whereby symmetry about the y axis means doubling each area to get the total area.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what shape will I get after rotating the area

Comment: @J.Dane see my added graphic to my answer.

Comment: Should there be a hole in the middle or not?

Comment: Can you check out my edit?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. I added the void at the center as dashed lines.

Comment: In the end, should I multiply it by 2 cause of the symmetry about the y-axis?

Comment: Yes, if you use the limits of integration I stated in my answer, the total area will be double the sum of the definite integrals of these. If you are including the area of the center void, the limit of integration is from 0 to 1. Again doubled.

Comment: Okay thank you very much I really appreciate your help